# Multiregion replication - Cloud SQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform

We are running our services in GCP and also using Cloud PostgreSQL. As part of our Multi -region or Disaster recovery strategy. I believe currently Cloud SQL does not support multi-region data replication.

In that case what would be the best strategy to go for?

Answer (score 1):

In multi-region mode, if your data need to be consistent across all region, asynchronous replication won't work. Spanner is design for this kind of use case (multi region transactional database)

If you need to have a DRP on multi region, the [backups are already multi regional](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/locations)

> A multi-regional location is a large geographic area, such as the United States, that contains at least two geographic places. Multi- regional locations are only used for backups.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the best practices for [Disaster Recovery Planning](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/dr-scenarios-planning-guide) and for [Disaster Recovery Scenarios for Data](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/dr-scenarios-for-data) in the public documentation.

For Cloud SQL you can make daily backups and store them in different regions, zones or even in multi-regional buckets providing geo-redundancy to your data.

On Cloud SQL you can directly enable the High availability regional option and this will let you perform failover in case of a distress situation on your Cloud SQL zone. Even if multiple Google's facilities are in the same Zone or Region all of them are physically separated from each other, and served by different basic services (such power plants in each facility) making the event of 2 facilities not able to serve very unlikely

Comment: I shall check the documents and links you have shared for the MR

Answer (score 1):

Cloud SQL for PostgresSQL support [cross regional](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication#cross-region-read-replicas) replication now.